# Connect signal to slot, but call the slot only once and then auto-disconnect them

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, observer-pattern, signals-slots

Consider this JS code:

```
function handleSig() {
    emitter.someSig.disconnect(handleSig);
    // do some work here
}

emitter.someSig.connect(handleSig);
```

Can it be written without the explicit disconnect and the named function?

Ideally, I'd like something like this:

```
emitter.someSig.connect(
    function() {
        // do some work here
    },
    Qt.SingleShotConnection
);
```

Near-duplicate: [Automatically disconnect after first signal emission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15263364) - but that question is about Python and mine is about QML and C++.

Comment: What a problem to call to `disconnect()`?

Comment: @folibis: 1. Then the `handleSig` name is triplicated, 2. It's harder to read, and 3. Can't define the  handler inside the `connect` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a small helper function, which does the disconnecting for you, like such:

```
function connectOnce(sig, slot) {
    var f = function() {
        slot.apply(this, arguments)
        sig.disconnect(f)
    }
    sig.connect(f)
}
```

As demonstration of the usage:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: myWindow
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600
    color: 'white'

    signal action(string name)

    function slot(name) {
        console.log(name)
    }

    Button {
        text: 'connect'
        onClicked: {
            connectOnce(action, slot)
        }
    }

    Button {
        y: 80
        text: 'action'
        onClicked: {
            action('test')
        }
    }

    function connectOnce(sig, slot) {
        var f = function() {
            slot.apply(this, arguments)
            sig.disconnect(f)
        }
        sig.connect(f)
    }
}
```

The upper two Buttons will connect `slot` and `slot2` in single-shot mode to the signal `action`.
The Button *action* will fire the signal `action` which will execute the slots as many times as they are connected. Then they will be immediately disconnected.

You might put the function `connectOnce` into a library to have it to your avail where ever you need it.

---

This solution is easily extended to a more general form, that will connect a function to be executed `n` times by introducing a counter in the closure:

```
function connectN(sig, slot, n) {
    if (n <= 0) return
    var f = function() {
        slot.apply(this, arguments)
        n--
        if (n <= 0) sig.disconnect(f)
    }
    sig.connect(f)
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this! :)

Answer (score 6):

I found an answer for C++ here, though it's a bit inelegant:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/67272/how-to-create-a-single-shot-one-time-connection-to-a-lambda/2

Code from that link:

```
QMetaObject::Connection * const connection = new QMetaObject::Connection;
*connection = connect(_textFadeOutAnimation, &QPropertyAnimation::finished, [this, text, connection](){
    QObject::disconnect(*connection);
    delete connection;
});
```

I'm still holding out for better C++ answers, and for a QML answer.

Comment: you could use a `shared_ptr` for the connection, then you don't have to `delete`, because the lifetime is managed in the capture clause

Answer (score 0):

It would probably most convenient to make a template implementing the same syntax as a regular `QObject::connect` call.

I've made these two templates below, using Stefan Monov's own answer. The first is method pointer based, the second one is lambda based.

```
#ifndef  CONNECT_ONCE_H
# define CONNECT_ONCE_H

# include <QObject>
# include <memory>

template<typename EMITTER, typename SIGNAL, typename RECEIVER, typename... ARGS>
void connectOnce(EMITTER* emitter, SIGNAL signal, RECEIVER* receiver, void (RECEIVER::*slot)(ARGS...), Qt::ConnectionType connectionType = Qt::AutoConnection)
{
  auto connection = std::make_shared<QMetaObject::Connection>();
  auto onTriggered = [connection, receiver, slot](ARGS... arguments){
    (receiver->*slot)(arguments...);
    QObject::disconnect(*connection);
  };

  *connection = QObject::connect(emitter, signal, receiver, onTriggered, connectionType);
}

template<typename EMITTER, typename SIGNAL, typename RECEIVER, typename SLOT, typename... ARGS>
void connectOnce(EMITTER* emitter, SIGNAL signal, RECEIVER* receiver, SLOT slot, Qt::ConnectionType connectionType = Qt::AutoConnection)
{
  std::function<void (ARGS...)> callback = slot;
  auto connection = std::make_shared<QMetaObject::Connection>();
  auto onTriggered = [connection, callback](ARGS... arguments) {
    callback(arguments...);
    QObject::disconnect(*connection);
  };

  *connection = QObject::connect(emitter, signal, receiver, onTriggered, connectionType);
}

#endif
```

About the lambda based template, I couldn't get it to compile when directly declaring `std::function` as a parameter, as the compiler couldn't recognize a lambda parameter as a valid candidate... which is why I'm declaring `SLOT` as a template parameter, and then casting it to `std::function`. It's not as concise as I would've liked, but it works.